# iPad FormSheet/PageSheet modal view, when rotated fill entire screen.T

Tags: ipad, rotation, xamarin.ios, modalviewcontroller

I have a iPad application, which has a `UITabBarController` as the root controller. From one of the tabs, I have a `UIToolBar` which contains a `UIBarButtonItem`, when clicked launches a Modal View.

The modal view appears in the correct size when first launched (in both landscape and portrait) however if you rotate the device, the modal view will then expand to fill the screen - regardless of how much you rotate the device from that point onwards.

I'm launching the modal view from the tab bar and I've set the `ModalPresentationStyle` in the view to be presented.

This affects the ModalView regardless of whether I set it to `FormSheet` or `PageSheet`.

Has anyone experienced similar behaviour, if so, how did you solve it?

Many thanks

**EDIT**

I've also noticed that since 4.2 when using a Modal Style Page/FormSheet that the view behind the Modal View isn't dimmed out anymore - am I presenting the view wrong or is this just standard on 4.2?

**EDIT 2**

Code:
In my default `UIViewController` I simply present the Modal view as follows:

```
void HandleNewMsgButtonTouch(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   PresentModalViewController(new ComposeMsgView(), true);
}
```

In the modal view itself, I've specified in the `LoadView` override:

```
public override void LoadView()
{
   base.LoadView ();
   ...
   // initialser code related to the view
   ...
   View.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.None;
   ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.PageSheet;
   ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve;
}
```

I've overriden the `ShouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation` to always return true as well.

Regardless of whether I use Formsheet / Pagesheet, they both appear the correct width when first launched (whether in landscape or portrait - I'm aware PageSheet will fill the portrait view) however on rotation, the modal view will then fill the screen (as if I had presented the ModalView with FullScreen).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the comment, try this:

```cs
void HandleNewMsgButtonTouch(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UIViewController oController = new ComposeMsgView();
    oController.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.PageSheet;
    PresentModalViewController(oController, true);
}
```

LoadView() is too late to set the properties.

Previous content:
Please post some code. The view is definitely dimmed, also in 4.2.
I assume that you are setting the presentation style on the wrong controller, because "PageSheet" is transformed to fullscreen when in portrait mode.

You have to set the presentation style on the controller you want to show in the moda view and not on the one which IS showing. So if your controller to show is "oToShow" and the one you are showing from is "oCurrent", you would have to set the style for "oToShow".
Try setting it to FormSheet which will always be on top and never goes fullscreen.

René

Comment: Please see latest edit for code example - As far as I'm aware, I've presented the view correctly (i.e. setting the presentation style in the view controller I'm presenting).

Comment: Have you tried:

void HandleNewMsgButtonTouch(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
UIViewController oController = new ComposeMsgView();
oController.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.PageSheet;

 PresentModalViewController(oController, true);
}

Comment: I just tried that and it worked like a charm. If you make it an answer I will mark it correct. Many thanks!

Comment: So did I earn the bounty? If you don't give it away today, half of it will be lost.

Comment: Sorry about the delay, had car troubles last night so that took up most of my evening! You have the bounty now :)

Answer (score 2):

you can work around it by using a different style, like

**UIModalPresentationFullScreen:** This is the default style and as the name suggests causes the modal view to be presented full screen exactly as with the iPhone

**UIModalPresentationPageSheet:** The modal view occupies the full screen height but the width is set to the width of the screen in portrait mode. This means that when the device is in portrait mode it still occupies the full screen. However in landscape mode it leaves some of the underlying master view to still be visible, but dimmed as the user cannot interact with the uncovered master view controller.

**UIModalPresentationFormSheet:** Both the width and height of the modal view are set to be smaller than the screen size. The modal view is centered on the screen and the uncovered areas of the master view controller are dimmed to prevent user interaction. If the modal view makes used of the keyboard the modal view is moved upwards to make room.

**UIModalPresentationCurrentContext**: The modal view is displayed using the same style as the parent master view controller.

also remember to adjust size and position because it would otherwise always be shown in PageFormSheet's default size.

hope this helps 
Alex

Comment: I probably should've clarified in the question that I've already set the ModalPresentationStyle to be either FormSheet or PageSheet. When first launched either appears the correct size, its when rotated that it then fills the screen.

Comment: Oh ok could you post the code you are using to create and present the modalview? Lets se if we can figure this out :)

Comment: Please see latest edit, I've added the basic code I used to present the modal view

Answer (score 0):

```
View.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight;
```